# og:type 'article' on Facebook share button

Tags: php, facebook, image, share, article

Recently, Facebook has changed the format of some shared posts. Specifically posts to share links. By testing I found that the difference was to define the post how to 'article'. The links defined how to 'articles' published with the big picture, however if you do not specify that it is a 'article' leaves a small image with the description on the right.

http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/131108113602877288.jpg
[Example of old posts with a small picture]

http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/131108113602194357.jpg
[Example of new posts with a big picture]

Using meta tags og: type I can say that it is a 'article' and when it is published large image is displayed.

What I want is to do the same with a share button using the php SDK. I do not know how to indicate that it is a 'article' and get to show me the big picture.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“I do not know how to indicate that it is a 'article' ”_ – by stating that in the `og:type` meta tag embedded in the HTML of the URL that you are sharing …

Comment: The effect is different. If from the Facebook page share on my wall a URL that contains the meta tag og: type, shows the big picture. If I share the same url from the share button, it shows the small picture. A mystery ...

Comment: anybody? I need help :(